# C Sockets recv: connection reset by peer

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to use sockets to get a small JSON test file, which is hosted on my website (http://a-cstudios.com/text.json). When I do this

```
long numbytes;
char *request = malloc(sizeof(char) * 300);
sprintf(request, "GET %s \r\nHOST:%s \r\n\r\n", restOfURL, baseServer);
// restOfURL = "/text.json" baseServer = "www.a-cstudios.com"
send(sockfd, request, strlen(request) + 1, 0);
char buf[1024];
if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, 1024-1, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("recv");

}
```

I get `recv: connection reset by peer`. But if I use the same code, where `restOfURL` is `/index.html` and `baseServer` is `www.google.com`, this works fine, and `buf` will contain the text of `index.html`. Why won't this work for the file on my website?

Comment: Doesn't a GET-request also need `HTTP/1.1` (or `1.0`) at the end?

Comment: You are sending invalid HTTP and the host is closing the connection. Did you put the HTTP/1.1 in the right place? And why use malloc() rather than allocating the array on the stack?

Comment: @EJP and Kninnug Thanks for pointing that out, that did fix the problem. If one of you posts that as the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam BTW, `sizeof(char)` is == 1 per definition.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post full code, I am going to take a stab at it and make an assumption:

You populate the format string of `"GET %s \r\nHOST:%s \r\n\r\n"` with `restOfURL` and `baseServer`

However, during the time of the `sprintf` call restOfURL isn't initilized so you're pushing garbage data into the first `%s`

Either post more of your code or make sure you initialize resOfURL

Comment: `restOfURL` is definitely initialized. I thought it would be pointless to post the other code, because it really has no effect on the error.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam, Another suggestion is to make sure send() is sending the full amount, It returns the amount of bytes it successfully sent. I don't see anything that is obviously missing or incorrect.

Comment: If 'restOfURL' wasn't initialised it would be null and a SIGSEGV would result, not this behaviour. send() sends the full amount in blocking mode. You seem to be just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kninnug pointed out, you need the HTTP version field (e.g., `HTTP/1.1`) at the end of the first line of the request. I just want to point out that you should not include the null terminator when you send the request. That is, change the `send` statement to

```
send(sockfd, request, strlen(request), 0);
```

Also, it is a good practice to always use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` to prevent buffer overflow, although to be really safe you still need to check for truncation.